# One Virtual Machine with Multiple Services

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

Want to know if one virtual machine on Azure can be linked with multiple Cloud Services, on different ports.

For example:

CloudService1 : VirtualMachine:80

CloudService2 : VirtualMachine:81

CloudService3 : VirtualMachine:82

Is it at all possible to configure these kinds of setup on Azure at the moment?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This is impossible.

`Cloud Service` as such is a container and boundary for a cloud deployment. One Cloud Service has only one Internet Facing IP Address (known as Virtual IP Address or just a VIP). It also has its own unique addressable name in the `.cloudapp.net` zone. One Cloud Service can have more than one Virtual Machine inside. But one virtual machine can reside in one and only one cloud service.

Could you elaborate a bit more on the requirement to have more than one cloud service mapping to the same VM? What is the reason behind that?

Comment: Hi astaykov, thanks for the response and explanation. 

Reason why we are looking into this is that we have a few VMs running at the moment, and some of them are utilising it at a very minimal point, thus we are thinking if we can merge all these VMs into one VM, and having multiple points of entry should cater for a different addressable name for each client.

Comment: perhabs you can utilize the Instance Level Public IP Address feature (in preview!) described here: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/virtual-machines-instance-level-public-ips-now-in-preview/ and here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn690118.aspx

Comment: Or just use different Public PORTs for each VM. You can still have just one cloud service, but with multiple endpoints assigned and each Endpoint will route connection to a different VM. This is also a solution, especially when you are OK with using different ports.

Comment: Alright, thanks astaykov! Different port access directly is a bit risky for us, as most clients accessing the VM will probably forget to put in the port.

Comment: Anyways, we figured another way around it, so thanks for the replies!